# Android Video Editing using ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-editing

I am using ffmpeg library for video editing by using bin ffmed file in my android code. All works fine but when I crop the video and rotate it, it takes too much time and usually got stuck.

This is the method I call for video cropping.

```
 public void rotateAndCropClip(String in, String out,int rotate, ShellCallback callback) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
    cmd = new ArrayList<String>();

    cmd.add(mFfmpegBin);

    // Input file
    cmd.add("-i");
    cmd.add(in);
    cmd.add("-vf");

    if(rotate == 1){
        cmd.add("crop=360:480:0:0,transpose="+rotate);
    }else{
        cmd.add("transpose="+rotate+",crop=480:360:0:0");
    }

    cmd.add("-preset");
    cmd.add("ultrafast");
    cmd.add("-c:a");
    cmd.add("copy");

    // Output file
    cmd.add(out);
    execFFMPEG(cmd, callback);
}
```

Is there any way I could stop freezing my app and boost the processing or any other way/ library for video croping?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is how it works!

As you are already using

```
cmd.add("-preset");
cmd.add("ultrafast");
```

it is still better than others
I'd recommended you to use....

```
  cmd.add("-threads");
  cmd.add("5");
```

FFMPEG will stay slow, but this will improve the performance.
I hope it helps :)

Comment: Is there any tutorial to integrate ffmpeg in android studio?

Comment: With latest android studio ndk.Ndk depreciation exception occurs